# Conditional value imputation: Setting 'Not available' to 0 for non-smokers?

Tags: r, substitution, imputation

I have a question about a problem with imputation of values in R. In particular, I have two variables: a categorical variable called "Do you smoke" where the survey asked if a person is currently smoking (code 1), smoking in the past (code 2) or not (code 3). The second variable is "number of cigarettes smoked in a day". The problem is that this data is considered as "Not available" for people that answered that they don't smoke currently, even if I think that it should be 0.

**I want to apply a code to say that when the variable "currently smoking" is equal to 2 or 3, then the number of sigarettes must be 0 for the specific observation. Do you know how I can do this? Thank you in advance.**

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example with some toy data:

```r
smokers_df <- data.frame(currently_smoking = c(1, 3, 2, 1, 1, 3, 3, 2, 1, 1),
                         number_of_cigs = c(10, NA, 5, 25, 12, NA, 0, 10, 1, 17))
smokers_df
```

```
   currently_smoking number_of_cigs
1                  1             10
2                  3             NA
3                  2              5
4                  1             25
5                  1             12
6                  3             NA
7                  3              0
8                  2             10
9                  1              1
10                 1             17
```

```r
idx <- which(smokers_df$currently_smoking %in% 2:3)
smokers_df[ idx, 'number_of_cigs' ] <- 0
smokers_df
```

```
   currently_smoking number_of_cigs
1                  1             10
2                  3              0
3                  2              0
4                  1             25
5                  1             12
6                  3              0
7                  3              0
8                  2              0
9                  1              1
10                 1             17
```